# Issue with recaptcha 2.0 php server side

Tags: php, recaptcha

I am desperately trying to make my form works.

But I am having issue with validating the recaptcha server side.
I have been looking around and going over my form a thousand times making tests, I know it doesn't pass the step of the recaptcha, but can't figure it out.

Here is my piece of code :

```
//variable :
$recaptcha = $_POST['g-recaptcha-response'];

//test captcha
if($recaptcha != '')
{
    $secret = " MY KEY HERE";
    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $var = file_get_contents("https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=".$secret."&response=".$recaptcha."&remoteip=".$ip);
    $array = json_decode($var,true);

    //check if captcha ok then check fields empty
    if($array['success'])
```

Please let me know if you can find anything wrong.
Thank you.
(indeed I removed my security key)

Comment: Err, isn't the request to the api suppose to be a post request?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: Youre doing a GET request, according to the [doc](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify). The method should be POST.

Comment: The API says POST, but GET actually works fine, is easier to code, and is just as secure.

Answer (score 1):

In my testing, I ran into two problems that you might be having.

1. The `remoteip` argument is optional. When I removed it, everything worked. Here's why: I was testing with both client and server machines on private IP's behind a firewall, so the `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` value on my server was 192.168.x.x. Google saw the public IP of my NAT firewall, so that is what `siteverify` tried to match against.
2. You can only check a given `response` once. If you try to check it again, it will always fail. So during testing you need to use a fresh one each time.

Also, you can simplify your PHP code a bit by using:
    `"...siteverify?secret=$secret&response=$recaptcha");`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
$secret = "YOUR-SECRET-KEY";

```
$verifyResponse = file_get_contents('https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secret . '&response=' . $_POST['g-recaptcha-response']);
$googleResponse = json_decode($verifyResponse);
if ($googleResponse->success)
{
    $captchaVerified = true;
}
```